# Why do I need explicit CR when sending HTTPS in Java?

Tags: java, http

I'm writing a simple HTTPS client in Java (exploring ideas for interesting/fun labs for my web programming course).  In order to get the web server to respond, I have to explicitly add a '\r' to the end of each line.  (If I don't, the web server replies with status 400 and "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.")

Should I have to explicitly add "\r"; or, is there a configuration I'm missing? (In other words, is there a way to tell Java to automatically add the CR?)  Interestingly enough, I also tried to run `openssl` from the command line on my Mac to grab a web page, and I had to add `-crlf` to the command.

When I use a "regular" socket to connect to and HTTP server on port 80, I don't have this issue (similarly when using `telnet`).  So, who exactly is being picky?  Is the HTTPS protocol different?  Is there a way to get Java to use '\r\n' instead of just '\n'?

My code is below:

```
public class HTTPSClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("www.emu.edu", 443);

        socket.startHandshake();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));

        out.println("GET / HTTP/1.1\r");
        out.println("host: www.emu.edu\r");
        out.println("connection: close\r");
        out.println("\r");
        out.flush();

        /*
         * Make sure there were no surprises
         */
        if (out.checkError())
            System.out.println("SSLSocketClient:  java.io.PrintWriter error");

        /* read response */
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP headers are lines, and are separated from the request body by a blank line. The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not whatever `println()` might do on your system. This has nothing to do with SSL whatsoever.

Comment: Good point.  I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP standard clearly says that `\r\n` is required. Most servers though accept a simple `\n` too - but some actually have a strict (and correct) interpretation of the standard. My guess is that you've tested different servers with "regular" sockets than you did with your Java application. And as with `telnet` - depending on the setup it might actually send `\r\n` instead of only `\n` as line end.

Comment: Telnet uses the same line terminators as HTTP, and in fact the HTTP specification refers to Telnet line terminators rather than specifying them itself IIRC.

Comment: @user207421: Yes, traditionally. But in current telnet versions there is  crlf toogle to define this behavior, which means it depends on the current setup.

Comment: What I mean is that the Telnet RFC defines a line terminator and all other RFCs that use line protocols such as POP3, HTTP, etc, explicitly refer to it rather than defining their own. There have been Telnet options to change the terminator from almost the beginning.